# Matching current route with react router

Tags: reactjs

This app is wrapped inside a Router, to find current url I use pathname, this is the only thing that seems t work on my attempt,

```
<Router history={history}>
  <SegmentMenu {...this.props} {...this.state} />
  <Route path="/" exact render={() => <Home {...this.state} pagename='Home' />} />
  <Route path="/auth" render={() => <Auth {...this.state} />} />
  <Route path="/terms" component={Terms} />
  <Footer />
</Router>
```

On every `componentWillMount` I run this to find url and add some logic to the menu:

```
 componentWillMount = (props) => {
    if (window.location.pathname === '/') {
      this.setState({ pagename: 'Anytime, anywhere.', home: true });
    }
    else if (window.location.pathname === '/dashboard') {
      this.setState({ pagename: 'Dashboard', dashboard: true });
    }
    else if (window.location.pathname === '/privacy') {
      this.setState({ pagename: 'Privacy', privacy: true });
    }
    else if (window.location.pathname === '/auth') {
      this.setState({ pagename: 'Account', auth: true });
    }

  ...
```

This is getting super long, how can I make this better? `pagename` is title of the screen and the next variable is `onFocus`

Comment: When you go to a particular route using <Link>, then react router automatically adds object having location, match, history objects. You could use `location.pathname` to get the route you clicked on. No need to test every route and you should create `<PrivateRoute/>` instead of `<Route/>` if some route requires authentication.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to store you route config in an array that can be used later to check if current route matches the path. `react-router` provides a `matchPath` function which can be used to check if the current `props.location.pathname` matches the route object. This way you can create a HOC function which will add the current active route object as a prop to your component.

See: https://codesandbox.io/s/0ikhi

#### Example

routes.js

```js
import DebugComponent from "./DebugComponent";

const routes = [
  {
    title: "Home",
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    component: DebugComponent
  },
  {
    title: "About",
    path: "/about",
    exact: true,
    component: DebugComponent
  }
];

export default routes;
```

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import routes from "./routes";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          {routes.map(route => (
            <Route {...route} key={route.title} />
          ))}
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

DebugComponent.js

```
import React from "react";
import withActiveRoute from "./withActiveRoute";

const DebugComponent = props => (
  // You have access to `props.activeRoute.title`
  <pre>{JSON.stringify(props.activeRoute, null, 2)}</pre>
);

export default withActiveRoute(DebugComponent);
```

withActiveRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { matchPath, withRouter } from "react-router";
import routes from "./routes";

const withActiveRoute = Component => {
  const ActiveRoute = props => {
    const activeRoute = routes.find(route => {
      return matchPath(props.location.pathname, route);
    });

    return <Component {...props} activeRoute={activeRoute} />;
  };

  return withRouter(ActiveRoute);
};

export default withActiveRoute;
```