# How can I match if the current route matches a pattern in React Router Dom v6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I've got:

```
export const ACCOUNT_PORTAL_PATHS = [
      'home/*',
      'my-care/*',
      'chats/*',
      'profile/*',
      'programs/*',
      'completion/*',
    ]
```

If the current path is any of those, I want to know. I managed to get the current path with:

```
const { search: searchParams, pathname } = useLocation();
```

and that yields, in this example:

```
pathname: "/my-care/1234"
```

What's the best way to match?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matching current route with react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208129/matching-current-route-with-react-router)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to know if you are on a matching path, you can use the [`matchPath`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#matchpath) function and test that *some* account path prefix is a match to the current `pathname`.

Example:

```
import { matchPath } from "react-router-dom";

...

const { pathname } = useLocation();
const isMatch = ACCOUNT_PORTAL_PATHS.some((path) =>
  matchPath(path, pathname)
);
```

[image: Edit epic-shtern-gyuolz]

Comment: I don't want to make new routes. I want to know if the current route matches one of those

Comment: @Shamoon I'm working on a demo for that. I was about to also ask what use case you are actually trying to solve for.

Comment: I can't using this on a custom function

Comment: @huykon225 Sorry, I don't understand your comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: @DrewReese I mean I have to use mitchPath on a react component or react hook, Am I correct?

Comment: @huykon225 `matchPath` is a regular function, so it can be used anywhere... right in a React component function body, a callback, a custom React hook, etc. Does that answer your question?