# React Router Dom v.5 --> v.6 - matchPath bug

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm upgrading my React app from React Router DOM v5.3.0 to v6.3.0 and have I this bug in the the `matchPath` function, the console says it expects to get 2 types arguments but got 1, here is my code:

```
import {
    createStyles,
    Divider,
    List,
    ListItem,
    ListItemIcon,
    ListItemText,
    ListSubheader,
    makeStyles,
    TextField,
    Theme,
    Toolbar,
} from '@material-ui/core';
import BusinessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Business';
import HomeIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Home';
import PersonIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Person';
import SettingsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Settings';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete/Autocomplete';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { matchPath, useNavigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useGetRealms } from 'src/lib/hooks/realm/useGetRealms';
import GrainIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Grain';
import { useSnackbar } from 'notistack';
import { Realm } from 'src/lib/model/api/realm';
import { UserStorage } from 'src/lib/model/api/userStorage';

const useStyle = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        nested: {
            paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
        },
        nestedUS: {
            paddingLeft: theme.spacing(6),
        },
    }),
);

const SiderBody = () => {
    const classes = useStyle();
    const push = useNavigate();
    const location = useLocation();
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    const [realmSelected, setRealmSelected] = useState<Realm | undefined>();
    const { enqueueSnackbar } = useSnackbar();

    const [userStorageSelected, setStorageSelected] = useState<
        UserStorage | undefined
    >();

    const { realms } = useGetRealms();

    useEffect(() => {
        const match = matchPath<{ Realm: 'string'; UserStorage: 'string' }>( //error is here
            location.pathname,
            ['/realm/:realm/us/:userStorage', '/realm/:realm/'],
        );
        if (!match && realms && realms.length === 1) {
            setRealmSelected(realms[0]);
            if (realms[0].userStorages.length === 1) {
                setStorageSelected(realms[0].userStorages[0]);
                push(
                    '/realm/' +
                        realms[0].name +
                        '/us/' +
                        realms[0].userStorages[0].name,
                );
```

Comment: API doc shows matchPath to have one generic type argument, but the d.ts file (router.d.ts) shows two.

Comment: In RRDv6 the [`matchPath` function](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#matchpath) takes only 1 type argument.

Comment: @DrewReese  the online docs say that. But the type definitions say this: 

 * see https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#matchpath
 */
export declare function matchPath<ParamKey extends ParamParseKey<Path>, Path extends string>(pattern: PathPattern<Path> | Path, pathname: string): PathMatch<ParamKey> | null;

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by doing this :

```
const paths = ['/realm/:realm/us/:userStorage', '/realm/:realm/'];
const location = useLocation();
const match = paths.find(path => matchPath(path, location.pathname));
```

instead of this :

```
const match = matchPath<{ Realm: 'string'; UserStorage: 'string' }>( //error is here
            location.pathname,
            ['/realm/:realm/us/:userStorage', '/realm/:realm/'],
```

thank you 'll for the help @nil @Drew Reese

Comment: Ah, I see what you are using it for now. Seems very similar to my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71787942/8690857) for handling matching an array of paths.